# How to display an error form with cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I want to know if there is a way to show an error form with cakePHP but in another view that it is not default.

This is my default View where I add data to my DB:

[Default view for add data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV5yw.png)

But I have another view where I use the same form just with a different style:

[My other view where I can add the same data too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAVnB.png)

I have this validation in my Model:

```
var $validate = array(
    'cantidad' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Rellena este campo'),
    'articulo_id' => array(
            'rule' => array('checkArticulo', 1),
            'on' => 'create',
            'message' => 'El artículo seleccionado ya fue agregado, intenta con otro.'
        )
);      

function checkArticulo($data, $limit){
    $now = new DateTime();
    $articulo_agregado = $this->find( 'count', array('conditions' => array('AperturaArticulo.articulo_id' => $data, 'AperturaArticulo.created >=' => $now->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))));
    return $articulo_agregado < $limit;
}
```

My field 'cantidad' must not be empty and my field 'articulo_id' must not be twice by day.

If you see in the second picture I have added already the article called 'TORTILLA 900GR'. If I try to add the same article in **'My other view where I can add the same data too'** I get my validation successfully but the error is displayed in the **'Default view for add data'**.

I just want to display that error in my **'My other view where I can add the same data too'**

thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean Validation with custom form / without formhelper. We can do these validations in the controller. Took the code sample from [Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html) .

The method $this->< MODEL >->validates() in your Controller will only return true or false. To manually work on the validation errors, you'll need this:

```html
if ($this-><MODEL>->validates()) {
    // it validated logic
} else {
    // didn't validate logic
    $errors = $this-><MODEL>->validationErrors;
}
```